# JProfiler elapsed time different from actual load time

Tags: jprofiler

We're running into a strange problem with JProfiler 7.1.1 where it displays an elapsed time for a given HTTP request completely different from the one obtained with Firebug or a manual test - 2.5s compared to 7.5s.  Default session settings are used.  JProfiler has always proven to be reliable, I'm a bit stumped by this behaviour.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

**Update 1** YourKit also provides accurate results, so this is clearly related to JProfiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, JProfiler shows time in the **runnable thread state**, not elapsed times. If you want to see elapsed times, adjust the thread state selector in the upper right corner to "All states".

For more information, see [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/07/thread-states-in-cpu-profiling-views.html).